# In gui, font looks thicker than usual

Tags: init-file, fonts

I started using Emacs a few days ago and facing the problem.
I use "M+ 1mn" for programming so I set this for Emacs. But It looks thicker than usual.(in Geany, VSCode, Xfce Terminal ...)

How do I fix that?

Relevant part from init.el

```lisp
(when (member "M+ 1mn" (font-family-list))
  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "M+ 1mn-12")))
```

https://pastebin.com/4ducG3PH
This is my init.el.

[image: image for comperison]
Left is Emacs and right is Neovim with Alacritty.

- Version: 26.3
- OS: ArchLinux (kernel: 4.19.72-1-lts)
- WM: i3wm

Answer (score 2):

I found a .el file for M+ 1mn in Gist.
https://gist.github.com/makotoy/3929218

And changed my init.el like

```
;;(when (member "M+ 1mn" (font-family-list))
;;  (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "M+ 1mn-12")))

(create-fontset-from-ascii-font "M+ 1mn:pixelsize=16:weight=normal:slant=normal:spacing=m" nil "mplus1mn")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-mplus1mn" 'unicode
                  (font-spec :family "M+ 1mn" :spacing 'm :size 16)
                  nil 'prepend)
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "fontset-mplus1mn"))
```

(I changed the size because I found that 12 is too small for me)

now It looks same to other application.
[image: improved pic]

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate how this solves the problem? Link-only answers are strongly discouraged.